# How to search the given text into marklogic XHTML file, like clt+f

Tags: xquery, marklogic, cts-search

I have below XHTML file saved in the marklogic with the URI(/54ab8c234f3c8ce1f5c30ddc).

I need to search the Marklogic DB based on the string (if it is tag name or attribute name or text in the XHTML).

I am able to search only text either attribute. But not able to search at a time all.

Note: if I pass "SS_Default"(it is a attribute value) string it will return the URI of marklogic or if I pass the "META" (it is a tag name) it should return the corresponding URIs or if I pass "Narrowed by"(it is a  text) it should return the URI of corresponding file.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <meta>
            </meta>
        <body class="Default">

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to search on full-text, as well as as on attribute values, and that you also want to be able to focus on text within specific attributes and/or elements? There are plenty possibilities, but it would help if you could elaborate a bit more on the exact search phrases, and expected answers. It is also appreciated if you can share some code of your own. That helps understanding your lines of thought..

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly! In the xml need to treat everithing as a string(attributed,text,elements). If we give keyword it should return the URI of the file.

Comment: It looks like you want to treat the XHTML as pure text, and not as structured information at all. In that case, you should load it as text using the format option. If you do that, you will not be able to use XPath on the contents of the document (it will just be one big text blob). cts:search is about searching textual content: tag names are not textual content.

Comment: Can you pls tell, how to get the document as a text at the time of search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kinds of searches you are trying to do are typically done differently from each other, as they are different types of data. For instance, if you want to search for "meta" and find documents that have that element, you are querying the structure. You can do that in MarkLogic with this kind of query:

```
cts:uris((), (), cts:element-query(xs:QName("meta"), ()))
```

When you want to search for "narrowed by", that's just text, nice and simple:

```
cts:uris((), (), "narrowed by")
```

If you want to search within attributes, that's typically done by specifying the attribute you want to search for:

```
cts:uris((), (), cts:attribute-value-query(xs:QName("body"), xs:QName("class"), "SS_Default"))
```

If you wanted to combine those, you could run an or-query. I suggest looking through the types of queries you plan to run and see whether they can be segmented this way. As mholstege notes, you could load the document as text and be able to search everything as strings, but you'd lose a lot of value in the structure, so it's probably better to step back and think about whether you really need to run those queries the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and help.
For cts:or-query, user only pass the keyword only. So we donot know the tag name and attribute name for perform the attribute search.
Please help on how we can load the document as a text in Mark-logic.
I donot want to load(save) a document as a text. After save/load user again download the document. I dont want to lose the data.

Is there any possibility to get the document as a text and perform the text search on the marlogic?

Comment: If you really want to insert it as text, then wrap the xhtml in "text { }" before passing to `xdmp:document-insert`. If you do that, you'll be passing on a lot of MarkLogic benefits. I'd lean toward prker's solution, where you store the text under `plain-text` but keep the structure available under `original`.

Answer (score 1):

On ingestion, you could use the envelope pattern by creating a wrapper around your original document.

```
<envelope>
  <original>
    <html>...</html>
  </original>
  <plain-text>
    put the plain text content of your html here
  </plain-text>
</envelope>
```

Your text searches can be executed on the plain-text element only and on returning the resulting docs you could return the content element.
But as Dave mentioned, you are loosing valuable information.
Here you can find documentation on ways to ingest data https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion