# How to load the xhtml document as a text and search the keyword in marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, xquery-3.0, adhoc-queries, cts-search

I have loaded the XHTML files in marklogic. But need to perform the search on attributes, elements and text.
So I need to get/load the document as a text and perform the search on document.

Below is the XHTML file.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <meta>
            </meta>
        <body class="Default">

        </body>
    </html>

Using below code I am ble to save text file but it will aloow to save (>0.2KB )small size file. I need to save upto 1 to 50MB files in marklogic DB.

Using below code I am able to save file as text but big file not able to save.
 ContentCreateOptions createOptions = ContentCreateOptions.newTextInstance();

 Content content = ContentFactory.newContent("/"+uID,filetext, createOptions);

 mlSession.insertContent(content);
```

Comment: Question relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796201/how-to-search-the-given-text-into-marklogic-xhtml-file-like-cltf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not quite sure about the use case behind this, but here you go:

If you really want to search full-text on element names, attributes, and text all together, without discrimination, you best insert it as text at ingest time. For instance with something like:

```
xdmp:document-insert(
    "/my.xhtml",
    text {
        xdmp:quote(
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                ...
            </html>
        )
    }
)
```

Or:

```
xdmp:document-load(
    "/server/path/to/my.xhtml",
    <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load">
        <format>text</format>
    </options>
)
```

After that you can simply do:

```
cts:search(collection(), "mytagorattrorterm")
```

Alternatively you could use xdmp:quote before doing a cts:contains or fn:contains, but that scales very badly, so you best do that only on one or a few docs at the same time.

HTH!

Comment: I am able to successfully save a document in my local marklogic and search the text using document-load function. But load function need the file path, they(user) are not recommended to save files in server with the path. With out path any-way to save text file in marklogic?

Comment: I gave two alternatives. Document-load requires files on the server, but the document-insert with quote doesn't.

Comment: I have tried document-insert, but it is given below error.
xdmp:document-insert("/my.xhtml", "<a>aaa</a>") -- arg2 is not of type node()
Query Used : 
let $arg := <a>aaa</a>
let $d:= xdmp:document-insert('/my.xhtml',xdmp:quote($arg))
return $d